# MySQL / Python Display the level of an user_id for each day the user had that level

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sorting, dataframe

By selecting user_id, date(timestamp) as date, level from a table i have the following output:

```
user_id  date    level
112   2017-10-13    16
112   2017-10-20    17
112   2017-10-22    18
112   2017-10-23    19
112   2017-10-30    20
112   2017-11-06    21
112   2018-05-17    22
```

I'm in a little bit of pickle and i can't find a way to achieve the following output. I'm trying to display the level of an user_id for each that user had a certain level.

The desired output for user_id 112 for example should be something like this:

```
user_id   date  level
112   2017-10-13  16
112   2017-10-14  16
112   2017-10-15  16
112   2017-10-16  16
112   2017-10-17  16
112   2017-10-18  16
112   2017-10-19  16
```

.
.
.
.

and so on for every user_id, dates interval and level.

Basically each user_id, having it's attributed level and each day it had that certain level

Could someone please help me?
I'm open to a resolve in both MySql and Python.

Thanks,
George

Comment: Do you just need to have the rows sorted by the date column?

Comment: How's this 'the difference between calendar days'?

Comment: @hbgoddard i'm not sure i understand what you mean. i need to show for each interval between two dates what level had every user_id.

Comment: @Strawberry i'm sorry for explaining this the wrong way, it's not difference i agree, i just need to show for each user_id, what level it had on each day, until it reached the next level.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry i understand, but this isn't an option for me right now. Would you happen to know a resolve through mysql?

Comment: For versions of MySQL older than 8, you could construct some kind of utility table - either a table of integers or a calendar table with all plausible dates (a depressingly small data set)

Comment: @Strawberry any other thoughts? Maybe something can be done through Python? :)

Comment: Python is application code

Comment: @Strawberry ok, i understand. Would you happen to know a resolve around this in Python?

Comment: so you don't have the rows 112   2017-10-14  16 -
112   2017-10-15  16 -
112   2017-10-16  16 -
112   2017-10-17  16 -
112   2017-10-18  16 - 
112   2017-10-19  16 in the DB, right?

Comment: @dmikester1 no, i don't have them.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but someone probably will...

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, just did.

Comment: I have started working on [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61e357/29)